# Trapping of Hot Atoms

Tags: ion-traps

Is there any possible way to trap atoms that are 'hot' and the trap itself doesn't cool them, but instead can continue to trap the atoms even at high temperatures? Where hot is defined as temperatures close to room temperature (ie 200-300 K).

I am aware that most traps operate at nK temperatures and then many traps (optical, magnetic) have a trapping potential temperature usually in the mK range; so is there a type of trap that exists to trap individual atoms at room temperatures while maintaining that temperature / and or not changing the temperature drastically.

Comment: Jack, asking related questions is fine (and even encouraged since questions with multiple questions are often closed for lack of focus), but when the same person asks very closely related questions, they should reference and link to the earlier question. It is important to be clear how the current question differs from the earlier one, and how any answers to the earlier question don't answer the current question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the Large Hadron Collider or the [Relativistic Heavy Ion Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Heavy_Ion_Collider) could be described as traps for very hot (i.e. energetic) particles - but the problem with energetic particles is that there is not much you can do with them apart from collide them with other energetic particles.